# Where is Python installed on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, mercurial

I am trying to set up Mercurial on a Raspberry Pi, but the instructions I am using are for Ubuntu. It suggests that the Python folder is `usr/bin/python`, but this does not exist on my Pi.

Where is Python installed on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: What OS is your Pi running?

Comment: Sorry a slightly important bit of missing info..... it is running raspbian

Comment: The command `which python` will tell you exactly where the executable is.  Do you need the link to the modules and all those goodies too, or just the executable?

Comment: Sources and importables are in e.g. `/usr/lib/python2.7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so it is in `usr/bin/` after all.

Just need to work out why the hgweb.cgi is displaying a blank page now. (I assumed it was because it was pointing at an incorrect directory, but this is now clearly not the case).

Comment: There are dozen possible reasons. For starters are you actually using it as a CGI or were you trying to tie it into your web server via some FastCGI wrapper or so? It just adds to the places where breakage can occur.